# How to implement ArcMenu for Android?

Tags: eclipse, android, android-library

I'm trying to get [ArcMenu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu) for my application.

The code runs great by itself, but I don't know how to make it work with another project.
It doesn't look like an Android Library project...

When trying to use this project with my own, this is what I get in Eclipse's console:

```
res/layout/arc_menu.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'fromDegrees' in package 'com.capricorn'
res/layout/arc_menu.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'toDegrees' in package 'com.capricorn'
res/layout/ray_menu.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'childSize' in package 'com.capricorn'
res/layout/ray_menu.xml:4: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'leftHolderWidth' in package 'com.capricorn'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I forked ArcMenu and published it on Github.

Now a better recode of it appeared: https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu

I recommend you use that one.

Comment: Dead link. Repost new link please.

Comment: As of 2014, I now recommend to keep an eye on the upcoming Floating Action Bar, coming with Android-L.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that on your XML you didn't properly define the namespace.

for example for all the android framework stuff is:
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

I suggest checking on your examples what would be for the ArcLibrary.

Comment: I have `xmlns:android` and `xmlns:custom` from com.capricorm. The example application works fine, but I don't know how to use it. No sample project, no usage.